# Symfony: cascade_validation option is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to upgrade my project from symfony2 to symfony3. I want to get rid of this deprecation warning

```
The "cascade_validation" option is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use "constraints" with a Valid constraint instead."
```

Below is my code

```
->add('student_name', 'collection', array(
                'entry_type' => TextType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'required' => false
                )
            ))
```

Can I just remove this line `'cascade_validation' => true` without causing any trouble? Or what would be the equivalent code in symfony3?

Comment: From the [migration guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form): `The cascade_validation option was removed. Use the constraints option together with the Valid constraint instead.`

Answer (score 23):

In Symfony3 you have to use `@Assert\Valid` constraint in your parent entity. You can remove the line `'cascade_validation' => true` in your FormType class.

```
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    protected $address;
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

[This Symfony commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/6c554c6c1af6ca6a454c4aaed2b88135667c1153) contains the change and full example how to upgrade.

Answer (score 17):

Just replace

```
'cascade_validation' => true, 

with 

'constraints' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid(),
```

Comment: This is also a good answer - there may be some circumstances where you want to set it for one particular form, but not for another that uses the same entity, in which case this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you to do Validation on an Entity, but from your code I'm not sure what your Entities are.
This link explains the [Valid annotation for an Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html).

But you should be able to remove "cascade_validation' => true" from your form. I'm worried that you still might get other errors.

Try it and see what happens.
You might want to also review this [Validation tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) for reference.